# Did the Human Mission to Inner Space (HUMIS) experiment ever take place?

Tags: mars, nasa, history, experiment

The final report of the 2003 [Caves of Mars Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caves_of_Mars_Project), formally ''[Human Utilization Of Subsurface Extraterrestrial Environments](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/710Boston.pdf)'' (PDF), talks a lot about the "Human Mission to Inner Space" (HUMIS) experiment.  Basically, they were planning to build a simulated Martian habitat in a cave in New Mexico or Arizona in 2004-2005 and test out a whole series of technologies.

However, I've been unable to find any results of the experiment, or even whether it took place in the end.  The closest seems to be [this paywalled paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1649667) that I'm unable to access, but reading between the lines it seems to be about the mouse experiments ("MOMIS"), not the planned human ones.

**Did the experiment ever take place?**  If it did not, why not, and why haven't we (as far as I can tell) tried again in the 18 years since?

Comment: Not a NASA "mission", this is somebody's proposal/wish list. NAIC apparently funded their study, which is what NAIC was for. Probably rejected due to their use of Comic Sans in the paper.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks, title amended.  Although the N in NAIC is NASA, so I'm not entirely sure I understand the distinction.